# Difference between "native" keyword and @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate annotation

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jvm-hotspot

Why use one over another and vice-versa?
Which is more performant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The javadoc comments for the `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate` annotation say the following:

> *"The `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate` annotation is specific to the HotSpot Virtual Machine. It indicates that an annotated method may be (but is not guaranteed to be) intrinsified by the HotSpot VM. A method is intrinsified if the HotSpot VM replaces the annotated method with hand-written assembly and/or hand-written compiler IR -- a compiler intrinsic -- to improve performance. The `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate` annotation is internal to the Java libraries and is therefore not supposed to have any relevance for application code."*

In short, a method with this annotation<sup>1</sup> *may* be specially optimized, but it depends on whether the HotSpot JVM *knows* how to optimize it.  The implication is that:

1. If the HotSpot JVM knows how to intrisify it, the Java method body is ignored.
2. If the HotSpot JVM *doesn't* knows how to intrisify, the Java method body will be used in the normal way.
3. Implementing the JVM code to do the intrinsification is non-trivial.
4. You cannot make use of this in your own code.  (It involves modify the core HotSpot JVM codebase.)

By contrast, declaring a method as `native` tells the JVM it *must* use a native code implementation.  (The `native` method doesn't have a body.)  The method's native code implementation *may* be provided by the JVM, or it *may* be provided by a dynamically loaded native library or DLL.)  The call will typically<sup>1</sup> be made via JNI / JNA and its calling sequence will be *less* performant than a conventional Java method call, and certainly an intrisified method call.

<sup>1 - In fact, the annotation is called `@IntrinsicCandidate` in Java 17.

2 - Some `native` methods in core Java SE classes (e.g. `Object` methods) are also marked as intrinsic.  These may get optimized calling sequences.</sup>

---

So to answer your questions:

> Which is more performative?

Intrisified method calls will be more performant.

> Why use one over another and vice-versa?

1. You (a regular Java programmer) can't usefully label methods in your apps as intrinsic. Regular and `native` methods your only options.
2. The JVM implementors have a choice, but given the extra work involved, they tend to only make a method intrinsic when it will give a significant performance benefit.  For example, it makes little sense to intrinsify the `native` method calls in `java.io.*` classes because the JNI method call overheads will be tiny compared with the other things that go on in a typical I/O operation.

Comment: A `native` method is not necessarily implemented with a slow JNI invocation or, in other words, being declared `native` and being intrinsic don’t have to be contradictions. E.g. `Object.getClass()` is declared `native` and an intrinsic JVM operation.