# Detect constructors that "should not" be used with reflection

Tags: java, reflection, jvm-hotspot

I have the following function:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T createInstance(String className, Object... args) {
    try {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
        Class<?>[] parameterTypes = Arrays.stream(args).map(Object::getClass).toArray(Class[]::new);
        return (T) clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(parameterTypes).newInstance(args);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error", e);
    }
}
```

The function is supposed to get a class name (as `String`), load it and, if a constructor which matches the `Object... args` is found, create a new instance of such object.

This code works but it may get invoked on `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate` methods.
For example, if the caller does this:

```
String str = createInstance("java.lang.String", "Some value");
```

... then the function would invoke this constructor of the class `java.lang.String`:

```
@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate
public String(String original)
```

My understanding of `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate` constructors is that the JVM will do a special processing for those, that's for example the reason why I'm able to do `String str = "some string";` but I'm not able to do `MyObject myObj = "some string"` (assuming that `MyObject` class has a constructor which takes a `String` in parameter).

At the same time, I kind of understand that these constructors are "unreliable" as they strictly depend on what the JVM guys decide. For example, the code would work as well with boxed primitives such as `Integer`:

```
Integer myInt = createInstance("java.lang.Integer", "3");
```

... but these constructors have been deprecated since Java 9 (and the new `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate`s of these classes are the `valueOf(...)` methods instead which are not constructors anymore).

My feeling is that I should reject any request on constructors that are either `@Deprecated` or `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate` in order to avoid callers building blocks on something that may potentially get deprecated one day.

- Can anyone confirm (or deny) my assumption?
- Assuming that my intuition is correct, I can easily `getAnnotation(Deprecated.class)` on the `Constructor` that I retrieve (since this annotation is public) but I cannot `getAnnotation(HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate.class)` since this annotation is package-private to `jdk.internal`. If that was the way, how can I detect all the classes that I should reject from building?

Comment: This is wrong: "that's for example the reason why I'm able to do String str = "some string"; but I'm not able to do MyObject myObj = "some string" (assuming that MyObject class has a constructor which takes a String in parameter)." That has nothing to do with @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66842504/difference-between-native-keyword-and-hotspotintrinsiccandidate-annotation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My understanding of @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate constructors is

Completely wrong.

HotSpot refers to the notion that the JVM will run all java code extremely stupidly/slowly, even slower than what you imagine, because it also does a boatload of seemingly pointless bookkeeping (how often does this 'if' branch one way vs. the other way - let's just count it for no reason).

... because with all that bookkeeping, the JVM can easily identify the 1% of the code that is eating 99% of the resources, and will then take quite a bit of time (and using all that bookkeeping it is doing) to generate some finely tuned machine code, specialized for the exact hardware you run on and optimized to run most quickly for the cases observed so far (that's the bookkeeping). And now you have extremely fast code instead. And given that this 1% of the code is actually eating 99% of the resources, that's why JVMs are actually really fast. That process of 'rewriting', that's hotspot. It's *purely* a Java-The-Virtual-Machine thing. Java-The-Language doesn't have hotspot, has no idea what it is, and you're talking about a language feature, ergo - no, that's not what @HotspotIntrinsicCandidate means, at all.

The reason you can write `String x = "hello"` is because the java language specification dictates this. That's it. That's the only reason. Because it's hardcoded in the spec. (Same for why you can write `Integer i = 5;` - because '5' is written down as a concept in the JLS, and 'hey if the code doesn't compile but turning a primitive into its matching wrapper type would make it work - then assume the programmer meant to do that and compile it as if it said `Integer.valueOf(5)` instead' - that is called 'autoboxing' and is also written in the JLS, which makes that work. Again, `@HotspotIntrinsicCandidate` has **nothing** to do with it).

@HIC refers to the idea that a JVM implementation is free to have a "pre-written" finely tuned machine code version of it, available straight within the JVM implementation itself, and the JVM runner should look for, and then use such a thing if it is available. It is no guarantee (but most JVM implementations do work this way; there's not all that much point doing bookkeeping on 'how often is `j.l.String`'s `hashCode()` method invoked' - anytime you shove strings in hashmaps means it'll get invoked, a lot. Might as well 'precompile' the machine code for it and inject it straight into `java.exe`. Why wait, right?

Given that it's **purely** an optimization move, presence or lack thereof has absolutely not one iota of effect on whether 'it is a good idea' to expose that constructor or not.

> My feeling is that I should reject any request on constructors that are either @Deprecated

Deprecation is an odd beast. It's used for many different things. There's no particular point in not using such constructors - sure, they *might* disappear in the future, but there are other reasons for Deprecation markers (sometimes it's just "This method is a bad idea, in the sense that most who use it are confused". For example, `j.u.Date`'s `getYear()` method is deprecated. I'll gladly take a bet at 1000 to 1 odds that it'll still exist 10 years from now. It won't be going anywhere. It's just a bad idea to use.

Which gets us to...

### This is a bad idea, period.

> Class<?>[] parameterTypes = Arrays.stream(args).map(Object::getClass).toArray(Class[]::new);

This doesn't work.

Trivial example:

```
class Example {
  public Example(Number n) {
    System.out.println("Hello!");
  }
}

...

createInstance("com.foo.Example", 5);
```

**The above does not work!!**

That's because invoking `.getClass()` on that 5 gets you `java.lang.Integer.class`. This is entirely 'compatible' with Number (it's a subclass of it) - `new Example(5)` works just fine. However, `getConstructor()` searches for *exactly* what you ask for, which is a constructor that takes 1 **Integer**. That's not there. You have a constructor that takes a supertype of Integer.

The one and only way to fix this is to use `.getDeclaredConstructors()`, go through all of them, and use `.isSubclass` and friends on each and every argument, also adding code to deal with varargs invokes if you like, and then using that.

This is *incredibly slow*.

More generally this approach means you take the worst aspects of laissez-faire compiler-less languages (usually called 'scripting languages'), and the worst aspects of java, whilst leaving the best parts out. What possible point does this serve?

I bet you're looking for some of these options:

### Build and compiler infra is much better than you think it is

There are *many* tools out there that are extremely smart about knowing what java code needs to be compiled (i.e. only the thing you changed), and that compiles *just* those things. For example, eclipse (the editor) will just automatically and near instantaneously keep all your stuff compiled, continuously. If this is an attempt to avoid the compile-build loop, there's no need for that.

You can even run `java foo.java` and the JVM will automatically compile and run it, for trivial one-file projects.

### There are java-esque scripting languages

You can just *run* javascript in java if you want. The GraalVM project has a java library that just runs javascript. Why not use that? If you'd like the syntax to be specifically java-like, there's beanshell and groovy.

### There are module systems and dynamic loaders

You can set up, in plain jane java (look up the ClassLoader class in the javadocs, or the OSGi project, for example), a system that can 'live-reload' classes in a running JVM. If the aim is that you can start a JVM, and then manually 'program in it' as it runs, you can use those.

### Debuggers are awesome

Debuggers can plug into running JVMs, even across an internet connection if you want, and just run code you type, on demand, in the middle of a breakpointed thread. In eclipse, for example, just set a breakpoint anywhere, run the thing (click the 'bug' button, that runs it in debug mode), and then just open the debug shell and type whatever you want. You can even access the local variables, they'll have whatever value they have when the breakpoint was hit. You can do this to 'live code' running on a server if you like.

### There's JSP

I strongly, strongly advise against this, but JSP is a thing where you can stick java code amongst your HTML in a `.jsp` file and have a web server just run this. It'll take care of everything - detecting that it changed, (re)compiling it, and running it. You can trivially edit the JSP file and just reload a page and now you're looking at the new stuff.

Some require you to tell it: Yes, please check for changes and re-compile.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer and the alternatives. Unfortunately that's really what I need and yes, the issue with the assignable subclasses is handled in the real implementation (the one I posted is very simplified). However your answer really clarified my evidently wrong understanding of what the HotSpotIntrinsic meant, so really thanks for that!

Comment: You can use `public static Object createInstance(String className, Object... args) { try { Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className); return new Expression(clazz, "new", args).getValue(); } catch(Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException("Error", e); } }` using `java.beans.Expression` to get a constructor lookup that handles subtype relationships, as well as boxing conversions. But it is limited to `public`/exported APIs. Note that declaring to return a type parameter `T` without any relationship to the arguments is fundamentally broken. Use a `Class<T>` argument if the caller knows the type.