Java Implementation of Math.exp()
Math.exp() delegate the computation to StrictMath, which in turns delegate it to the fdlibm library in C. At least this is how it looks from what is mentioned in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StrictMath.html.
However, this C implementation (https://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/e_exp.c) appears to give different results compared to what Java returns:
I'm evaluating
exp(-0.271153846153846134203746487401076592504978179931640625).
The C implementation gives:
0.7624991798148184063421695100259967148303985595703125->
0x1.86664ae1101cap-1
while Java gives:
0.76249917981481829531986704751034267246723175048828125->
0x1.86664ae1101c9p-1
Java code is just:
import java.math.BigDecimal;
double expon2 = Math.exp(-0.271153846153846134203746487401076592504978179931640625);
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(expon2).toPlainString());

C code is https://www.netlib.org/cgi-bin/netlibfiles.pl?filename=/fdlibm/e_exp.c.
How is this possible? I would expect a perfect match, instead.


your C result is incorrect; you must be doing something wrong ... or your implementation is broken


Can you show  segments, one in C and the other in Java, that demonstrate this? In other words, a Minimal Reproducible Example

@pmg you could maybe try and see what you get. Only two source files are needed and they can be downloaded from https://www.netlib.org/cgi-bin/netlibfiles.pl?filename=/fdlibm/e_exp.c

The Standard Library has a working version of exp() already. Only thing needed is to add -lm to gcc invocation :)

@pmg can you share the line? using -lm calls the fdlibm library? otherwise gcc has a different implementation of exp() which is https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_exp.c.html

"Only two source files are needed and they can be downloaded from ..."  We expect relevant code to be in the question body. To better understand how to use this site, it might help to Take the Tour, read How to Ask a Good Question, and pages they link to.

Java result is correct, so the fault is with the C code. You'll have to show how you test that instead.

https://godbolt.org/z/c19Pbze3x <== the compiler itself uses MPFR for a compile time constant rather than a runtime calculation

Note well that in both example codes, the argument is expressed to far more significant decimal digits than is meaningful for an IEEE754 double (about 15-16).

Note also that the example that you present as C is in fact C++, which is a different language.  That might make a difference to the result, though in truth, I'm inclined to guess not.

code all in C is provided in the question now. Let me know if you don't see that. @OldDogProgrammer

showed @GuyIncognito

The C code you show in the godbolt link calls exp and returns the same value as Java. However, I downloaded e_exp.c and fdlibm.h and called __ieee754_exp(1.0), and it returned 2.0 which is obviously wrong (should be e, 2.71828...). You should change your question to be only about the fdlibm library, why it returns seemingly incorrect results.

@pmg how can i save and send a link as you did? I re-used the link that you provided and put the code i wanted. It is the one on the question but apparently I am the only one that see the code that I have there, but others still see what you wrote

@JohnBollinger: Re “Note well that in both example codes, the argument is expressed to far more significant decimal digits than is meaningful for an IEEE754 double (about 15-16)”: That is incorrect. They are expressed to more digits than would change the value when the decimal is converted back to IEEE-754 binary64. However, they are meaningful; the digits OP presented show the exact values represented in the binary64 type, meaning that if you convert those values to decimal with a sufficient number of digits and correct rounding, you get those digits…

You need to click the share button so that the interface creates a new link with your changes

… This is important when working with finely engineered floating-point code.

@pmg thank you, done and modified the question

"Only two source files are needed and they can be downloaded" -- again, as already commented, external links are no good - they can be changed, edited, removed, ... invalidating the question !

That linked e_exp.c file is bizarre. It contains #include "fdlibm.h" at the beginning but seems to have a copy of fdlibm.h embedded in it, and that causes compilation problems. Do you know why?

fdlibm.h defines a macro __P that interferes with a macro of the same name define by <stdio.h> in my C implementation (Apple Xcode 15.4, macOS 14.6.1).

@EricPostpischil eventually fdlibm.h is only needed for the definition of the two mactos __HI and __LO. So you might delete the rest.

@Albert: That is not the question. Why is the file presented the bizarre way it is? The goal is not to get some scrap of code that compiles and diagnose why it does not work. The goal is to get the actual fdlibm code and see whether that works, and, if it does not, why. Some weird source file with fdlibm.h both included and embedded does not seem like the original code; it seems like some artifact of presentation on the web or other kludge, and that should be resolved before worrying about what is actually in the code.

Related: Rounding when ULP 1 - Java and C++

@EricPostpischil where do you get the impression that https://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/e_exp.c embeds fdlibm.h? I see no evidence of that.

@k314159: Further testing shows it is an artifact of the web interface. When I click on OP’s link, select “Plain text”, and click Start Download, the result is a web page that contains both the e_exp.c file and the fdlibm.h file as a single page. If I instead click on “Zip”, download it, and unzip it, then I get two separate files.

Using the BigDecimal constructor may be modifying the value. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7186298/721855. You may want to use BigDecimal.valueOf() instead.

@user85421 can we re-open it now?

@Albert - Why are you asking me ??? I have not voted for it to be closed

What are we supposed to do now? Java gives one result. Some C implementation with the given e_exp.c code give another result. How should anybody explain the difference? You have not shown the code that produces the result for Java. If you had that code, and it was analogous to the e_exp.c code at hand, you could examine each individual step in the computation and see where they diverge. Without that code, or if it is not analogous, what is there to say? We have two approximations to e^x, and they produce different results because they are different approximations.

Is the e_exp.c code you have presented identical to the exp code for fdlibm 5.3? Is your Java code using the code that should produce the fdlibm 5.3 result (i.e., not using non-strict math or using some math other than IEEE-754 binary64 — I am not completely familiar with Java and do not know whether importing BigDecimal will affect the math routines). For what it is worth, Maple says the Java result, 0.76249917981481829531986704751034267246723175048828125, is slightly closer to the mathematical e^x than the C result is.

@aled "Using the BigDecimal constructor may be modifying the value." - actually it's the other way around. BigDecimal.valueOf constructor uses the Double.toString() representation, whereas the constructor shows the exact binary representation (converted to decimal). BigDecimal.valueOf(0.1) -> 0.1, new BigDecimal(0.1) ->0.100000000000000005551... In other words, 0.1 is not really 0.1, and the BigDecimal constructor tells you what it really is.

@Albert, why did you edit the code out of the question? It's required here. As others have already told you, we won't go off-site or download external source files here. Questions must be self-contained. (I'm not a domain expert, otherwise I'd read the code and decide whether it should be edited back in. All I can do now is vote to re-close this question since it isn't complete.)

My understanding is that questions should not be edited in a way that invalidates answers. One of the answers has this: *"The question has been updated after it had been pointed out that we were using the wrong endianness for fdlibm. The question now is: why Java gives an answer differing from C by just one ulp."  Seems to me the edit in question did that.

@OldDogProgrammer, this question has 15 revisions. I'm not clear on which edit you're talking about, or which revision you think best represents the question and the answers. But in its current form, the question certainly isn't clear unless we visit a third-party site or download complete source files. That edit happened 21 hours ago and the final reopen vote was cast only 9 hours ago, which means this version, without the relevant C code, was current. It shouldn't have been reopened without an edit, and I don't have the domain expertise to make the right rollback or edit.

-1 and voting to close. OP was informed the code should be in the question itself, but still replaced the code with a link to some benighted tarball/zip file downloader.

@Chris I don't know which edit it was, either. But, the original question had "Using the C implementation of the function it gives: 0.728846153846153921307404743856750428676605224609375 while Java gives: 0.76249917981481829531986704751034267246723175048828125" That question was answered. The O/P then changed the question, so the two number differ only in the last digit place.  In my view, that should have been a different question.

You're not using the fdlibm library properly. __ieee754_exp is what they call an "elementary function", in other words it's an internal function that is used by the real exp function. Also, the library is multi-platform and does a lot of bit-twiddling and is very sensitive to CPU endianness, so it needs to be configured with the appropriate macros.
To use the library properly, you need to build it according to the instructions in the readme, and then include the built library in your application. Do not call __ieee754_exp directly.
Update
The question has been updated after it had been pointed out that we were using the wrong endianness for fdlibm. The question now is: why Java gives an answer differing from C by just one ulp.
The answer: the C fdlibm library and Java's StrictMath class actually give the same answer (which is not surprising, since StrictMath uses the same implementation as fdlibm):
jshell> Double.toHexString(StrictMath.exp(-0.271153846153846134203746487401076592504978179931640625))
$6 ==> "0x1.86664ae1101cap-1"

On the other hand, Java's Math class uses an intrinsic implementation and gives the same answer as the gcc library in C:
jshell> Double.toHexString(Math.exp(-0.271153846153846134203746487401076592504978179931640625))
$7 ==> "0x1.86664ae1101c9p-1"

In C:
printf("%a", exp(-0.271153846153846134203746487401076592504978179931640625));
Output:
0x1.86664ae1101c9p-1


The intrinsic implementation is typically the one that is microcoded into the processor, and gives a very slightly different approximation by the very last bit differing by 1.

So let me see if I understood. The source of the difference is the @IntrinsicCandidate keyword added on this method due to the fact that (as mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66842504/difference-between-native-keyword-and-hotspotintrinsiccandidate-annotation). "A method is intrinsified if the HotSpot VM replaces the annotated method with hand-written assembly and/or hand-written compiler IR -- a compiler intrinsic -- to improve performance." And then it also says:
"If the HotSpot JVM knows how to intrisify it, the Java method body is ignored."
In practice..

Java does not call StrictMath.exp (which is the body of Math.exp() ), but uses an assembly code version for performance optimizations. So there isn't any real code that is called and that can be translated into C, to obtain identical numbers between Math.exp() and a C version of it. Correct?

"So there isn't any real code that is called and that can be translated into C, to obtain identical numbers between Math.exp() and a C version of it." - could be correct, but not necessarily. The gcc library in C gives the same answer as Java's intrinsic Math.exp, but that's probably because the gcc library also uses the intrinsic version of exp. However, that doesn't mean that it can't be written entirely in C. It probably can. The difference in the result is just a difference in the rounding method used. The intrinsic method has rounded the last bit down, while fdlibm rounded it up.

in this case gcc library gives the same result, but it does not in other cases:
try exp(-3.076923076923077093880465326947160065174102783203125e-02)

@Albert the results of https://onecompiler.com/c/42qkutyjx and https://onecompiler.com/java/42qkuvakr look exactly the same to me.

I assume onecompiler.com simulates a x86 build, if you change it to x64 you will get a different results. This is another of the mystery which I would like to understand.

Note: i'm using MSVC compiler

Everything is running on x64, but the difference is between compilers. MSVC returns 0x1.f07c6e07475dcp-1 while gcc and both Java Math.exp and StrictMath.exp all return 0x1.f07c6e07475dbp-1. Not sure why MSVC is different, but it's just a rounding of the last bit.

Results under MSVC change depending on x64 or x86

The test #ifdef __LITTLE_ENDIAN does not work in your compiler, and the code instead uses the definitions for big endian, resulting in incorrect handling of the data.
Changing #ifdef __LITTLE_ENDIAN to #ifdef __LITTLE_ENDIAN__ or #if 1 will likely result in the code working your compiler.
Testing this with Apple Clang 15.0.0 on macOS 14.6.1 shows, before the change, the same incorrect result you report and, after the change, the correct result.
Apparently this code was not written to use the preprocessor symbols defined by GCC and Clang to indicate endianness.

In my case (Linux amd64), I removed the conditions around #define __LITTLE_ENDIAN in fdlibm.h, so it's now always defined, and now __ieee754_exp works correctly. This should be the accepted answer.

@k314159 and Eric, note that the result is not identical to the one that Java retrieved. I modified the question with the value that I get using the C code (tweaked thanks to the advice of Eric).

I can't tell you precisely why these two implementations yield
slightly different results in this case.  But I can tell you why it's
not surprising — it's basically expected — that two
implementations may yield slightly different results in cases
like this.
For certain "basic" operations — the canonical examples are of
course addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division —
IEEE-754 guarantees that you will always get a correctly-rounded
result.  If the true mathematical result is not exactly
representable, if the true result lies somewhere between two
different representable IEEE-754 numbers, you're guaranteed to
get the closer one.
But for other operations — and particularly for transcendental
functions like sin, cos, exp, and log — there is no such guarantee.
The reason is that it's an exquisitely hard, and generally
unsolved, problem to decide how hard you need to work to generate
correctly-rounded results for these functions in all cases.
Eric Postpischil has a very nice answer discussing this problem (perhaps not coincidentally attached to your other question on this topic).  If you work hard enough, you can generate as many exact digits as you want, but if you want a maximally efficient algorithm, that uses just enough extra precision to generate a correctly-rounded result (to some given finite precision) for every possible input, that's super hard.
For your problem, exp(-0.271153846153846…), the mathematically-correct result is (not surprisingly) not
exactly representable in IEEE-754 double precision.  The
mathematical result falls between two representable numbers —
and, as it happens, those two "straddling" representable numbers are precisely the two numbers that your two different implementations gave you.
Here are the details.  I have computed the "exact mathematical
result" using two different arbitrary-precision programs.  I've used bold highlighting to make it easier to see the digits that differ.




value
explanation




1
0.76249917981481829531986704751034267246723175048828125
0x1.86664ae1101c9p−1


2
0.76249917981481829531986704751034267246723175048828125
impl. #1


3
0.76249917981481834237…
exact result (bc)


4
0.7624991798148183423701219458277605732565114320577561612719…
exact result (mpcalc)


5
0.7624991798148184063421695100259967148303985595703125
impl. #2


6
0.7624991798148184063421695100259967148303985595703125
0x1.86664ae1101cap−1



To be clear:

Row 1 is an exactly-representable IEEE-754 value.  (Its hexadecimal representation is 3fe86664ae1101c9.)
Row 2 is the result you got from Java's Math class, and which (according to @k314159) "uses an intrinsic implementation and gives the same answer as the gcc library in C". [footnote 1]
Row 3 is the result computed using the Unix bc program.
Row 4 is the result computed using my own homebrew multiprecision calculator.
Row 5 is the result you got from Java's StrictMath class, and also from the fdlibm library.
Row 6 is the next exactly-representable IEEE-754 value after row 1.  (Its hexadecimal representation is 3fe86664ae1101ca.)

As I said earlier, the exact result falls between two representable numbers.  Those two representable numbers are as close as you can get in IEEE-754 double precision.
Now, which of the two representable values is closer?  Let's take a look.  I've added a "diff" column showing the differences between the decimal values:



value
diff.
explanation




0.76249917981481829531986704751034267246723175048828125

impl. #1 ("intrinsic")



4.7e−17



0.76249917981481834237012194582776057325651143205775616…

exact result



6.4e−17



0.7624991798148184063421695100259967148303985595703125

impl. #2 (fdlibm)



So in this case, we can see that the "intrinsic" result is actually significantly closer to the real value.  It is (for this one problem, at least) "correctly rounded".
I've gotten the impression that fdlibm  is very well implemented, but evidently it does not always produce correctly-rounded results for the exp function.  (Nor is it required to by IEEE-754.  I don't know what its published guarantees are for this function.)

Footnote 1.  "The gcc library in C" isn't a well-defined concept.  Systems with gcc are often (though not always) set up to link against glibc, the GNU C library.  I'm perfectly willing to believe there are versions of glibc which give result #1, although the one I tried, as well as Apple's C library used with clang on my Mac, both gave result #2, the same as fdlibm.

It's confusing to talk of "Java result" vs "C result". It's actually "fdlibm result" (which includes the Java StrictMath library and the C fdlibm library) vs the "intrinsic result" (which includes the Java Math library and the C GNU libm library).

@k314159 Wording adjusted.  (Alas, it blew out my second table.)
